# Prison Architect obj.Misbehaviour

Tags: lua

I´am currently working on a mod that causes guards to call backup when they see a misbehaving prisoner. This is what I got on pastebin.com : http://pastebin.com/322dRw3s The part that doesnt work is "Line 18" or

```
if Prisoner.Misbehaviour ~= "0" then
```

This should call guards to a Prisoner if he is not Misbehaving.
They just dont do anything.
Notes:
Changing 0 to "None" doesn´t work.
[This may help answering my question](https://github.com/aubergine10/Prison-Architect-API/wiki/obj.Misbehaviour)

Thanks for quick answers!

Comment: [edit] the post and put the code in question. Do not link to pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

try without `"`

```
if Prisoner.Misbehaviour ~= "0" then
```

to

```
if Prisoner.Misbehaviour ~= 0 then
```